# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm, homebrew

Using Homebrew, on Mac OSX 10.7.5

```
$ brew install openssl
Error: openssl-1.0.1e already installed

$ rake test.rake
rake aborted!
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I acknowledge that there are other questions like the one in title, but none of the solution seems to work. I have tried those at various points, with no success:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

```
rvm remove 1.9.3
brew install openssl
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

I decided to check openssl version and noticed this:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

Hopefully that is indeed the problem and the fix is as simple as making sure my laptop detects the correct OpenSSL.

But how do I fix this, so I have it use Homebrew's newer OpenSSL instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update certificates:

```
sudo curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o "$(ruby -ropenssl -e "p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE")"
```

Although this is considered to be not safe as the certificates are downloaded without `https` and there is no way to tell if they were not changed on the way.

RVM has updated code that will use OSX certificates to update the file and will pull automatically dependencies, you can get it with:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: I tried both those, and neither worked: First suggestion gave me
"Warning: Failed to create the file "/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem": No such 
Warning: file or directory
  0  245k    0  1222    0     0   2721      0  0:01:32 --:--:--  0:01:32  8427
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1222)"

Comment: Stupid homebrew ruby 2.0 seems to install rvm but I can't find where or it's actually not being installed, so I can't use rvm. And the first way still fails for me with the same error as above by Craig.

Comment: As per the comments here: http://toadle.me/2015/04/16/fixing-failing-ssl-verification-with-rvm.html I updated homebrew on Yosemite and it worked. 
`brew update`
`brew upgrade`

Answer (score 15):

it worked for me using rvm

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on mpapis's answer, I executed these commands that fixed the problem for me.

```
$ cd ~
$ rvm get head
$ rvm requirements
```

This gave me two key pieces of feedback:

```
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/myuser/.rvm/ is complete.
RVM Reloaded!
```

and

```
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Updating certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'.
```

After that, I didn't get the error anymore.

Comment: This was able to solve my issue.  As a heads up to others reading this post, it took about two hours for `rvm requirements` to finish.

Answer (score 0):

on my mac running 10.8.3 i had this problem too, however i had a problem with the above solution because when i tried to do
    rvm get head
    install 1.9.3

or

```
rvm requirements
```

i got Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install... which is a nightmare in its own right see [Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install...' on Mac 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473115/error-running-requirements-osx-brew-libs-install-on-mac-10-7) for proof

anyway i got it working by doing

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem > 
mv cacert.pem /Users/USER/.rvm/usr/ssl/cert.pem
```