# Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install...' on Mac 10.7

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

Trying to install brew on a last generation Macbook Pro and keep getting the following error:

> Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite',
>
> please read /Users/allegrascrugham/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1368142352_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_apple-gcc42_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log

I tried removing and reinstalling RVM & Brew with no luck.

Comment: Is RVM/Ruby in a working state? Homebrew will need ruby to do it's thing

Comment: What's in `1368142352_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_apple-gcc42_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log`? Any errors there?

Comment: Hi, did you solved the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: Brew is missing some dependencies. This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632543/error-installing-any-ruby-version-with-rvm-on-osx

Answer (score 50):

I had the exact same error when running `rvm requirements`. That log file doesn't give any hints other than a package failed to install.

This is what worked for me:

go from the last package before it fails, in your case `sqlite`. Then install manually like so:

```
brew install sqlite
```

Then run `rvm requirements` again, it will probably fail at an earlier package. Repeat the steps above.

Comment: I had to install about 10 packages manually, but that fixed this issue for me as well.

Comment: Although rvm was giving me messages that "Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password," it didn't and this method worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 16):

You have to install these dependences manually, try

> brew install automake

if it gives you error of missing link of automake something like this

> You must `brew link autoconf' before automake can be installed

then try these commands

> brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
>
> brew link --overwrite autoconf
>
> brew install automake

it will install automake and then you can try again to install ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Had similar issues on a new OS X Mountain Lion install.

Followed tutorial http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/ until step 6 when I got this error. Also checked log file which didn't indicate exact problem.

Decided to verify if RVM had installed.

```
type rvm | head -1
```

Didn't show rvm as being 'sourced'. So, opened new terminal to check. Sure enough, new terminal returned `rvm is a function`. So, closed older terminal session & re-copied install rvm script into new terminal.

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable

After this, all went well. **Did not do any manual installs.** One slight detour I took was to `brew install pkg-config` after reading the post [Error installing any ruby version with RVM on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632543/error-installing-any-ruby-version-with-rvm-on-osx) just before running the above curl command again - this was likely unnecessary too.

Then,

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

You might get a message:

```
>A RVM version 1.20.11 (stable) is installed yet 1.20.10 (stable) is loaded.
Please do one of the following:
  * 'rvm reload'
  * open a new shell
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for auto reload with msg.
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for silent auto reload.
```

Type `dvm reload` or one of the other options. Verify with `dvm -v`, `ruby -v`

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution: install Xcode Command Line Tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The log file that this error tells you to check has this info:

> There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
>
> Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.
>
> Check Homebrew requirements
>   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation

After running brew tap --repair, rvm was able to auto install the missing dependencies via homebrew and install my ruby without problems. no need to manually install each package or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a package you are trying to pull might be unreachable.  I am seeing the same error and the log file shows an error trying to download http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz which I can confirm is currently unreachable via wget:

--2013-05-13 21:09:52--  (try: 2)  http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
Connecting to pyyaml.org|70.87.222.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Operation timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

Also confirming that pyyaml.org is unreachable for me.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the described problem on my MacBook 2,1 running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 after executing `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enable --rails`. After trying again the installation was successful without making any additional changes.

Give brew&rvm a second chance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue with MacOS High Sierra and this thread was super helpful. Ended here after running `brew install gcc49` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750395) then had to run `brew upgrade automake` and `brew upgrade coreutils` I already had this installed and my X-code was up todate.