# installing Rails 1.9.3 using RVM gives error message

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm learning Ruby from Michael Hartl's tutorial. I'm following the steps one by one, but I can't get passed this one. After installing RVM, the instructions are:

1. `rvm get head && rvm reload`
2. `rvm install 1.9.3`

I can do the first line in the terminal, but when I do the 2nd I get the following error message:

```
"Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl',
please read /Users/sg/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p429/1370816489_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_apple-gcc42_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl.log"
```

What can I do to fix this error? I'm using OS X Mountain Lion on a Retina MacBook Pro if that makes a difference.

Comment: so what does the log file the error tells you to read say?

Comment: You're installing Ruby 1.9.3, not Rails. There's a __big__ difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
rvm requirements
```

See if you have installed everything that is required

Comment: Thanks. This is what the error message I got was. "Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/dupes
Already up-to-date." And also "Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42". The second one I shortened. Now what to do?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473115/error-running-requirements-osx-brew-libs-install-on-mac-10-7