# RVM Ruby Installation Fail on OS X 10.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I am receiving an error when running the RVM command to install Ruby on my OSX machine.  The output is below:

```
ThisComp:~ *************$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    330      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   330
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  18860      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  9.7M
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/************/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/*************/.profile /Users/*************/.bashrc /Users/***********/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/*********/.bash_profile /Users/**********/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/*************/.rvm/ is complete.

# msutyak,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/*************/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile

  * No new notes to display.


rvm 1.25.26 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system......
Installing required packages: automake...
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/***************/.rvm/log/1401388968_ruby-2.1.2/package_install_automake.log
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  82 > [[ -t 1 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  82 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_warn()  139 > printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_libs_install()  63 > case "$_system_version" in
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_libs_install()  70 > return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

When I type `brew tap --repair`, I receive the following error:

```
Pruned 0 dead formulae
```

Does anyone know what is going on and what I can do to rectify the situation? I'm not sure why there are package installation errors.

EDIT:

```
ThisMachine:~ ************$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
Would remove:
/usr/local/bin/ifnames
/usr/local/bin/autoupdate
/usr/local/bin/autoscan
/usr/local/bin/autoreconf
/usr/local/bin/autom4te
/usr/local/bin/autoheader
/usr/local/bin/autoconf
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ifnames.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/config.sub.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/config.guess.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autoupdate.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autoscan.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autoreconf.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autom4te.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autoheader.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/autoconf.1
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.el
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.elc
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.el
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/version.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4f
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4f
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/foreach.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/INSTALL
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/specific.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/general.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/autotest.m4f
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/autotest.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoscan/autoscan.list
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/XFile.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Request.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Getopt.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/General.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Configure_ac.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Channels.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/types.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/status.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/specific.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/programs.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/oldnames.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/libs.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/lang.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/headers.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/go.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/functions.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/fortran.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/erlang.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/c.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoupdate.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autotest.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoscan.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoheader.m4
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4f
/usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4
ThisMachine:~ *************$ brew link --overwrite autoconf
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... 
Error: Could not symlink share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp is not writable.
ThisMachine:~ *************$ brew install automake
Error: You must `brew link autoconf' before automake can be installed
```

Running brew link autoconf:

```
ThisMachine:~ ************$ brew link autoconf
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... 
Error: Could not symlink share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
Target /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite autoconf

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
```

Answer (score -2):

Installation of automake has failed. Try installing it manually using brew:

```
brew install automake
```

This post has some additional tips for installing automake in case you get other errors: [Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install...' on Mac 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473115/error-running-requirements-osx-brew-libs-install-on-mac-10-7)

Comment: When I run brew install automake, I get the error: 

Error: You must `brew link autoconf' before automake can be installed

Comment: Take a look at the link. It describes that exact issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473115/error-running-requirements-osx-brew-libs-install-on-mac-10-7

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but I tried following that thread, and ran the brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf command and ran into the error in the EDIT.  Any ideas?