# RVM Requiremets tries to tap deprecated homebrew/versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, homebrew

I'm trying to get a Ruby on Rails project running on my Mac OS Sierra (10.13.3) machine. When I navigate to the Rails folder, RVM tells me the following:

```
Required ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-1.9.3-p392"'
```

However, when I do that install, I get the following:

```
$ rvm install "ruby-1.9.3-p392"
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required custom packages: homebrew/versions.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_install_custom homebrew/versions',
please read /Users/petercormack/.rvm/log/1518211184_ruby-1.9.3-p392/install_custom.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

When I look at that log file, I see the following:

```
[2018-02-09 12:36:30] requirements_osx_brew_install_custom
requirements_osx_brew_install_custom () 
{ 
    \typeset __tap;
    for __tap in "$@";
    do
        brew tap "${__tap}" || return $?;
    done
}
current path: /Users/petercormack/podcastsi18n
PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin:/Users/petercormack/.node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/petercormack/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl
command(2): requirements_osx_brew_install_custom homebrew/versions
+ typeset __tap
+ for __tap in '"$@"'
+ brew tap homebrew/versions
Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
+ return 1
```

So. RVM seems to be stuck on this idea of installing homebrew/versions, which has been completely removed by Homebrew. I've updated Homebrew. I've updated RVM. I've tried to trick Homebrew into having that tap available (not successful). I've tried to trick RVM into thinking that's not a required custom package (couldn't figure out how). Nothing seems to be working. Help!

## EDIT

I got around the problem by actually upgrading the project to use ruby-2.1.0 . Worked like a charm, but of course didn't actually resolve the original issue. Thank you for the answers below, and hopefully they'll help out some other poor soul in the same situation!

Comment: I just inherited a Rails app that uses ruby-1.9.3-p392 (I'm on macOS 10.13.3 too)...my fix was to bump the patch level to 551 - I'll eventually upgrade to the latest stable but just needed to get the app working on my dev env.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tripped up on this as well. While it's not a final answer with the help of a kind soul on Github I was able to find a temporary solution to this issue.

If you are running macOS 10.10 or later then you should run `brew install gcc49`. This will help RVM as it now won't try to tap the deprecated homebrew versions repository. If you are on an earlier version have a look at this [function in RVM](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/c20852ea9cfce5e14c994d035cf8f0d0dbf07797/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew#L226) for the appropriate version of gcc to install.

I have documented the issue I was encountering over here: 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4303

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. This happens only when installing a ruby version older than 2.0. I was able to get past this using `rvm autolibs read-only` then install the ruby again. This will tell rvm to use existing dependencies and to skip the error if something is missing. Just then try to manually install all the required packages using Brew.

https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Comment: I encounter this problem with the message that said "Try brew `tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable." and your suggestion help resolve the issue, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to install Ruby 3.0 . For me just updating RVM to the latest version fixed the issue:

```
rvm get stable
```